# Implemented expression tree as follows in java using stacks(LinkedList), but it has errors

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I was trying to implement expression tree by using stacks(LinkedList) and I have the following error when I compile it.

```
Note: ExpressionTree.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ExpressionTree implements ExpressionTreeInterface{
    private ExpressionNode root;
    public ExpressionTree(String expression){
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        String[] s = expression.split(" ");
        int i=0;
        for (String a:s){
            if (a == "0" || a == "1" || a == "2" || a == "3" ||a == "4" ||a == "5" ||
                    a == "6" ||a == "7" ||a == "8" ||a == "9"){
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                ExpressionNode e = new ExpressionNode();
                e.operand(b);
                l.add(e);
            }
            else if (a == "*" || a == "/" || a == "+" || a == "-"){
                ExpressionNode e = new ExpressionNode();
                e.operator(a);
                e.right = (ExpressionNode)l.get(l.size()-1);
                e.left = (ExpressionNode)l.get(l.size()-2);
                l.remove(l.size()-1);
                l.remove(l.size()-2);
                l.add(e);
            }
        }
        root = (ExpressionNode)l.get(0);
    }
    public int eval(){
        return eval(root);
    }
    public int eval(ExpressionNode r){
        if (r.left!=null && r.right!=null){
            if (r.getOperator() == "+"){
                return eval(r.left) + eval(r.right);
            } else if (r.operator == "*"){
                return eval(r.left) * eval(r.right);
            } else if (r.operator == "/"){
                return eval(r.left) / eval(r.right);
            } else {
                return eval(r.left) - eval(r.right);
            }
        } else {
            return r.getOperand();
            }

        }
    private static class ExpressionNode{
        int operand;
        String operator;
        ExpressionNode left;
        ExpressionNode right;
        public void operator(String operator){
            this.operator = operator;
        }
        public void operand(int operand){
            this.operand = operand;
        }
        public String getOperator(){
            return operator;
        }
        public int getOperand(){
            return operand;
        }
    }
    public String postfix(){
        return postfix(root).trim();
    }
    private String postfix(ExpressionNode s){
        if (s.left == null && s.right == null){
            return Integer.toString(s.getOperand());
        } else{
            return postfix(s.left) + " " + postfix(s.right) + " " + s.getOperator();
        }
    }
    public String prefix(){
        return prefix(root).trim();
    }
    private String prefix(ExpressionNode s){
        if (s.left == null && s.right == null){
            return Integer.toString(s.getOperand());
        } else{
            return s.getOperator() + " " + prefix(s.left) + " " + prefix(s.right);
        }
    }
    public String infix(){
        return infix(root).trim();
    }
    private String infix(ExpressionNode s){
        if (s.left == null && s.right == null){
            return Integer.toString(s.getOperand());
        } else{
            return infix(s.left) + " " + s.getOperator() + " " + infix(s.right);
        }  
    }
}
```

Also, I created the following test class but it again has the following error.

```
at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:555)
at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:476)
at ExpressionTree.<init>(ExpressionTree.java:27)
at Testfile.main(Testfile.java:4)
```

```
public class Testfile {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String a = "34 2 - 5 *";
        ExpressionTree s = new ExpressionTree(a);
        System.out.println(s.eval());
    }
}
```

Where did I do wrong? I think I used a lot of recursion, so maybe there was a mistake from there, but I cannot figure out where.

Comment: Did you recompile with the parameter "-Xlint:unchecked" like the error suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your code :

**First issue is**  You can't compare string in java using == operators you need can use function like .equals() to compare two string values. So, this code fragement :

```
if (a == "0" || a == "1" || a == "2" || a == "3" ||a == "4" ||a == "5" ||
                a == "6" ||a == "7" ||a == "8" ||a == "9")
```

gets changed to :

```
 if (a.equals("0")|| a.equals("1") ||a.equals("2") || a.equals("3") ||a.equals("4") ||a.equals("5") ||
                    a.equals("6") ||a.equals("7") ||a.equals("8") ||a.equals("9"))
```

same goes with this part of code fragment :

```
else if (a == "*" || a == "/" || a == "+" || a == "-")
```

you need to use .equals function in this as well.

Same issue is there in `eval` function as well in this part :

```
if (r.left!=null && r.right!=null){
        if (r.getOperator() == "+"){
            return eval(r.left) + eval(r.right);
        } else if (r.operator == "*"){
            return eval(r.left) * eval(r.right);
        } else if (r.operator == "/"){
            return eval(r.left) / eval(r.right);
        } else {
            return eval(r.left) - eval(r.right);
        }
    } else {
        return r.getOperand();
        }
```

**Second issue is** in input `expression` string ("34 2 - 5 *") one of the string is `34` but it wont satisfy this condition :

```
  if (a == "0" || a == "1" || a == "2" || a == "3" ||a == "4" ||a == "5" ||
                    a == "6" ||a == "7" ||a == "8" ||a == "9")
```

So, instead of checking whether your string is number or not by this way you can create helper function to do the same like this and call the same :

```
 private boolean checkStringIsNumber(String s) {
    boolean numeric = true;

    try {
        Integer num = Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        numeric = false;
    }
    return numeric;
}
```

**Third issue is** in these two lines :

```
 l.remove(l.size()-1);
 l.remove(l.size()-2);
```

Suppose your link list has two node at this point . After l1, l2. After executing first statement

```
l.remove(l.size()-1);
```

updated link list will  contain one node i.e. l1. Now if you execute this statement

```
 l.remove(l.size()-2);
```

It will throw exception as link list size is now 1 and l.size()-2 will return in -1 which is invalid index;

So, I suppose you want to remove last 2 nodes so you can do instead of these two statements this :

```
 l.remove(l.size()-1);
 l.remove(l.size()-1);
```

So, after resolving all these issues , **updated code of ExpressionTree constructor** is :

```
 public ExpressionTree(String expression){
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        String[] s = expression.split(" ");
        int i=0;
        for (String a:s){
            if (checkStringIsNumber(a)){
                int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
                ExpressionNode e = new ExpressionNode();
                e.operand(b);
                l.add(e);
            }
            else if (a.equals("*") || a.equals("/") || a.equals("+") || a.equals("-")){
                ExpressionNode e = new ExpressionNode();
                e.operator(a);
                e.right = (ExpressionNode)l.get(l.size()-1);
                e.left = (ExpressionNode)l.get(l.size()-2);
                l.remove(l.size()-1);
                l.remove(l.size()-1);
                l.add(e);
            }
        }
        root = (ExpressionNode)l.get(0);
    }
```

and **updated code of eval function** is :

```
 public int eval(ExpressionNode r){
    if (r.left!=null && r.right!=null){
        if (r.getOperator().equals("+")){
            return eval(r.left) + eval(r.right);
        } else if (r.operator.equals("*")){
            return eval(r.left) * eval(r.right);
        } else if (r.operator.equals("/")){
            return eval(r.left) / eval(r.right);
        } else {
            return eval(r.left) - eval(r.right);
        }
    } else {
        return r.getOperand();
        }

}
```

After making these changes above expression string works fine and gives result as 160.

Comment: Glad this was helpful to you